# IEnumerable<T> to CSV ... In the array processing

Tags: c#, csv

I have a 'IEnumerable to CSV' Extensions class.

My source code.

```
public static class CSVConverter
{   
    public static string ToCsv<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) where T : class 
    { 
        var csvBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(); 

        csvBuilder.AppendLine(String.Join(",", properties.Select(p => p.Name.ToCsvValue()).ToArray())); 

        foreach (T item in items) 
        { 
            string line = String.Join(",", properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null).ToCsvValue()).ToArray()); csvBuilder.AppendLine(line); 
        } 

        return csvBuilder.ToString();
    }

    private static string ToCsvValue<T>(this T item) where T : class
    {
        if (item == null) { return ""; }

        if (item is string)
        {
            return String.Format("\"{0}\"", item.ToString().Replace("\"", "\""));
        }

        double dummy;

        if (double.TryParse(item.ToString(), out dummy))
        {
            return String.Format("{0}", item);
        }

        return String.Format("\"{0}\"", item);
    }        
}
```

Not so processed array entry of data conversion is included .

Sample code

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string[] NickName { get; set; }
    }

    public void ConvertTest()
    {
        string csvData = new List<Person> {
            new Person
            {
                Name = "Harold",
                NickName = new string[] { "Bruce Lee", "Jackie Chan" }
            }
        }.ToCsv();
    }
```

csvData is "\"Name\",\"NickName\"\r\n\"Harold\",\"System.String[]\"\r\n"

ConvertTest () on the result of the array item not be processed.

So I want to be....

"System.String[]" --> "Bruce Lee, Jackie Chan"

How do I to?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what format you need, but maybee this will give some ideas.

```
public static class CSVConverter
{
    public static string ToCsv<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) where T : class
    {
        var csvBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        if (properties.Count() == 0)
        {
            csvBuilder.AppendLine(String.Join(",", items));
        }
        else
        {
            csvBuilder.AppendLine(String.Join(",", properties.Select(p => p.Name.ToCsvValue()).ToArray()));

            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                string line = String.Join(",", properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null).ToCsvValue()).ToArray());
                csvBuilder.AppendLine(line);
            }
        }
        return csvBuilder.ToString();
    }

    private static string ToCsvValue<T>(this T item) where T : class
    {
        if (item == null) { return ""; }

        if (item is string)
        {
            return String.Format("\"{0}\"", item.ToString().Replace("\"", "\""));
        }

        if (item.GetType().IsArray)
        {

            return item.ToString() + "\"" + ((IEnumerable<T>)item).ToCsv() + "\"";
        }

        double dummy;

        if (double.TryParse(item.ToString(), out dummy))
        {
            return String.Format("{0}", item);
        }

        return String.Format("\"{0}\"", item);
    }
}
```

I added a `if (item.GetType().IsArray)` to check if it's an array, then iterate those items.

Answer (score 0):

Self Answer

```
        if (item is string[])
        {   
            IEnumerable<string> list = item as IEnumerable<string>;
            return String.Format("\"{0}\"", String.Join(",", list).Replace("\"", "\""));
        }
```

Added to - string ToCsvValue(this T item) where T : class